# What are the potential problems that could occur when using PHP 5.3.6 with VC6 compiled Apache?

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2008

First off, I am [cross-posting this from Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/261864/what-are-the-potential-problems-that-could-occur-when-using-php-5-3-6-with-vc6-co) because I did not receive any responses there. If that is against the rules, I apologize.

What sort of issues could(should) I expect if I were to install 5.3.6(VC9 only) with a VC6 compiled version of Apache?

Comment: Why are you using apache compiled with VC6? It's probably best to use [apache compiled with VC9](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) if you are worried about possible compatibility issues.

Comment: Christopher, I understand that it would be best to use VC9 compiled Apache. I'm not sure that the reasoning behind my running VC6 compiled Apache is relevant to the question - I'm simply looking for potential problems that *could* occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no personal experience, but this [ServerFault article](https://serverfault.com/questions/140962/how-do-i-know-before-hand-whether-vc6-or-vc9-fits-me-when-installing-php-for-wind) gives some hints.
Problems that could occur are described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/140962/how-do-i-know-before-hand-whether-vc6-or-vc9-fits-me-when-installing-php-for-wind/140969#140969).

This [install description](http://www.websiteadministrator.com.au/articles/install_guides/installing_php533_pg2.html) may also be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although a little vague, it's probably the best answer I am going to get. As far as I can tell from that answer, it looks like memory management is the biggest potential problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it causes no issue at all. I've had that exact setup deployed on production sites several times (where I was not managing the server) and released projects with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just got [this](http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,72243,73354):

```
i tried the VC-9 version of PHP 5.3.6 with the "Unofficial WampServer Version 2.0j-32bit" and it works! in the phpinfo there is a line "Compiler MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)" so it is really the vc9 version working.

the unofficial wampserver (pampserver) can be downloaded here:
[sourceforge.net]

home page: www.pampserver.com

for those who want to add the php 5.3.6 version to the pampserver, do this:

0) at first, stop wampserver and make sure it is not running

1) download this [windows.php.net]

2) in "c:\wamp\bin\php\" create a folder "php5.3.6" and extract the downloaded zip file into this folder

3) in any folder with the previous version of php 5.3, find files "php.ini" , "phpForApache.ini" and "wampserver.conf" (eg. in the folder "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.3\" )

4) copy these 3 files into the new "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.6\" folder

5) now in the new "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.6\" folder, find files "php.ini" and "phpForApache.ini" and open both files in any text editor

6) replace all occurences of "5.3.3" (or the version number you copied those files from) with "5.3.6" and save

7) go to the "c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.17\bin\" folder and delete file "php.ini"

8) start wampserver and in the menu PHP -> Version select 5.3.6

9) voila! now you can open your localhost and see the phpinfo() page and check out the php version
```